# What's the difference between a WriteSteam and WritableStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

```js
const response = await fetch('https://www.google.com')
response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()).pipeTo(process.stdout)
```

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "transform.writable" property must be an instance of WritableStream. Received an instance of WriteStream

### Questions

1. What is the difference between Writable and Write steams?
2. Can the WriteSteam (`process.stdout`) be converted to a writable stream?

---

### Attempts

I tried to make stdout writable to no avail:

```js
// fails
process.stdout.writable = true
response.body.pipeTo(process.stdout)
```

Some methods that work include:

```js
// works
const response = await fetch('http://www.google.com')
const reader = response.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
for await (const chunk of reader){
  process.stdout.write(chunk)
}
```

```js
// works
Readable.fromWeb(response.body).pipe(process.stdout)
```

I don't exactly understand the difference between a "web" stream and a "node" stream, which I'm guessing are just source and destination, but I thought every I/O stream was able to redirect to each other.  It seems like using the `Readable.fromWeb` works, but what is it doing? It seems inefficient.

Can the reverse be done to `process.stdout`? Something like...

```js
response.body.pipeTo(new WritableStream(process.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

WriteStream is a stream that is writable to a file.

WritableStream is a stream that is writable to a destination. It can be a file, a socket, a pipe, etc.

Comment: Can `process.stdout` be converted to a Writable? Based on what you said, Writable seems like a more abstract parent class and should be able to use something more specific, like WriteStream as part of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> Can the reverse be done to `process.stdout`? Something like...

Yes, see [`Stream.Writable.toWeb`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamwritabletowebstreamwritable).